# Is it wise to allow "idempotent signups" by disabling RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

A couple of our users are trying so sign up again months after having last logged in. They get this error:

> A user with the specified ID already exists. Please choose a different one.

While trying to improve the experience for those users, I came across this setting:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
```

If I set `RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists` to `false`, the user is overwritten/replaced. So their password is changed and the claims are updated. As far as I can see, nothing *bad* happened.

From what I can see, the objectId stayed identical, and the user was only patched, not completely replaced. Custom properties are still there. Is there something else I am not seeing? I am considering simply turning the error off so our users can think they are signing up, even though the account is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what properties are being written ([PersistedClaims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#persistedclaims)), if its to have those written then there should not be a problem, that's all that will change.